# Сворачивание видео в угол экрана, как в youtube

Tags: java, android, видео

Есть ли библиотека, реализующая интерфейс сворачивания видео, как в youtube (когда оно становиться маленьким прямоугольником в нижнем правом углу)? Или как это можно сделать без них?